# Notes mail is rendered strange in outlook (EML)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, lotus-notes

I have some kind of strange behavior if I try to open a mail, which has been stored to a CMS with a Notes client, with an Outlook client. I found the reason is that there are =LF within the EML. They seem to be in the text every 72 chars, no matter what kind of text is written at this point, even within html tags.

Outlook shows these chars as they are in the file. Anyways if I open the same file in Notes it is shown correctly.

Why is this? Can I have the same behavior in an Outlook client? Is this even valid in a MIME message?

```
X-Notes-Item: CN=<infos>; name=OriginalFrom; flags=45


--0__=4EBB0C59DFDCC3088f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0C59DFDCC308
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Disposition: inline

<html><body>
<p><font size=3D"2" face=3D"sans-serif">Hallo zusammen,</font><br>
<br>
<font size=3D"2" face=3D"sans-serif">dieses Material ist ersetzt durch =
xxxxxxxx(Info auf der Zeichnung), welches wiederum ersetzt wurde durch =
xxxxxxx.(Info in xxxx)</font><br>
<br>
<font size=3D"2" face=3D"sans-serif">Der Arbeitsplan zu ist xxxxxxxx ka=
lkulierbar.</font><br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666402/quoted-printable-line-continuation-bug

It describes, that Outlook is checking the RFC2045 by the line endings. So the endings need to be (CR)(LF) instead of just (LF).

Comment: Hi, If your issue is resolved, it's recommended to mark it as an answer.

Comment: thank you so very much! this solved a big problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a standard part of the MIME `Quoted-Printable` transfer encoding. You're just looking at the raw source code of a very typical MIME message (a multipart one, judging by the `--etc` boundary indicator).

The problem is that for some reason, Outlook doesn't recognize it as such (either not seeing it as a MIME message at all, or not dealing well with the "multipart" bit) so it is not applying the decoding that each part needs.

If it was stored as a plain-text RFC822 message (usually in an .eml file, rather than Outlook binary .msg) then open it using a text editor and make sure the top-level headers aren't messed up; e.g. some systems insert blank lines in between headers, or fold long values incorrectly.